# How set proxy with username and password for `httpc` library?

Tags: proxy, erlang, elixir, httpc

I've tried the following without success:

```
:httpc.set_options( proxy: {{'proxy.int.mycompany.com', 8080}, ['localhost'], proxy_auth: {'developer', 'developer'}})
```

And

```
:httpc.set_options(proxy:  { {'proxy.int.mycompany.com', 8080}, ['localhost'], {'proxy_auth', 'developer', 'developer'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

[`:httpc.set_options/1`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html#set_options-1) expects a proplist.

```rb
:httpc.set_options(
  proxy: {{'proxy.int.mycompany.com', 8080}, ['localhost']},
  proxy_auth: {'developer', 'developer'}
)
```

Comment: I tried that. It gives`{:error, {:not_an_option, {:proxy_auth, {'developer', 'developer'}}}}` error.

Comment: It looks like you can set proxy_auth only in :httpc.request function.

Comment: Yes, I think the same. Thanks for confirming.